# Trying to make equal-sized cells in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

I'm trying to create a chessboard using a TableLayoutPanel of 64(8x8) cells, each cell to contain a PictureBox.
I also want the chessboard to expand and contract as the user grows or shrinks the form. As you can see, I haven't got very far!

I thought the code below would at least be a start and would display the cells as 64 equal size squares but as you can see, it doesn't.

```
    'Make all the cells of equal size
    For i As Integer = 0 To TLP_Chessboard.ColumnCount - 1
        Dim tableColumnStyle As New ColumnStyle()
        tableColumnStyle.SizeType = SizeType.Percent
        tableColumnStyle.Width = CSng(100 / TLP_Chessboard.ColumnCount)
        TLP_Chessboard.ColumnStyles.Add(tableColumnStyle)
    Next

    TLP_Chessboard.RowStyles.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 0 To TLP_Chessboard.RowCount - 1
        Dim tableRowStyle As New RowStyle()
        tableRowStyle.SizeType = SizeType.Percent
        tableRowStyle.Height = CSng(100 / TLP_Chessboard.RowCount)
        TLP_Chessboard.ColumnStyles.Add(tableRowStyle)
    Next
```

http://i40.tinypic.com/5d53l5.png

If, instead, I comment out this code and edit the rows and columns in the designer, setting each row and column to 12.5%, I get this:

http://i43.tinypic.com/2rrpilz.png

which is much closer to what I want but not close enough! 
Any ideas, please?